# What is the complexity of converting scala collection from one type to another?

Tags: scala, complexity-theory

I would like to know the complexity of converting scala collection operations like following ones :

```
List.fill(n)(1).toArray
Array.fill(n)(1).toList
ArrayBuffer( Array.fill(n)(1):_* )
```

I suppose that for those exemples we need to loop over all elements so it will be **O(n)**, unfortunately i don't know the subroutines under those conversions so the complexity may be optimized.

Don't hesitate to add complexity for others kind of scala conversions.

Answer (score 3):

I took a quick look at the source code, and they all appear to be O(n) as you thought.

Here's for example the subroutine `copyToArray` (used by `toArray`):

```
override /*TraversableLike*/ def copyToArray[B >: A](xs: Array[B], start: Int, len: Int) {
  var i = start
  val end = (start + len) min xs.length
  val it = iterator
  while (i < end && it.hasNext) {
    xs(i) = it.next()
    i += 1
  }
}
```

[source](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.1/src/library/scala/collection/IterableLike.scala#L248-L256)

As you can see it simply iterates over the collection linearly.